# JQuery animated splitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animated, splitter

I am lookin for a javascript splitter that can be docked and that I can animate. A little like the Ext.js one in this demo : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/simple-tasks/index.html. Anyone knows a one ?

I googled "javascript animated splitter" but the only one I found suitable for our needs was made with an older version of JQuery and did not work with the latest version. Here : http://krikus.com/js/splitter/

Since we already use Kendo UI controls, we need a lightweight free plugin with little dependencies. One built over JQuery would be nice.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [jQuery UI Layout Plug-in](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)? It says it's "inspired by the extJS border-layout".

I'm afraid though it isn't exactly lightweight. The minified version is about 22 KB (gzipped) plus you will need jquery ui draggable to enable pane resizing and jquery ui effects to enable pane animation.

Comment: Thanks ! That was exactly the kind of things I was looking for.